# Select sub-df of not more than a time threshold for each id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a time series `dataframe` where the logs of a particular may runs from several minutes to hours. For visualisation purpose, I have to slice the logs of each id to the first 15-minutes data.

Take the example of the df below:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
     {'id': [15,15,15,15,15,64,64,64,64,64],
 'timestamp': ['2016-04-01 00:05:00','2016-04-01 00:10:20','2016-04-01 00:13:01',
                '2016-04-01 00:14:00','2016-04-01 00:16:00','2016-04-01 21:04:59',
               '2016-04-01 21:13:05','2016-04-01 21:20:00','2016-04-01 21:25:25',
  '2016-04-01 21:59:59']}
)

df

    id      timestamp
0   15  2016-04-01 00:05:00
1   15  2016-04-01 00:10:20
2   15  2016-04-01 00:13:01
3   15  2016-04-01 00:14:00
4   15  2016-04-01 00:16:00
5   64  2016-04-01 21:04:59
6   64  2016-04-01 21:13:05
7   64  2016-04-01 21:20:00
8   64  2016-04-01 21:25:25
9   64  2016-04-01 21:59:59
```

By limiting the data of each `id` to 15-minutes from the start, I want to have the following `new_df`:

```py
new-df
    id     timestamp
0   15  2016-04-01 00:05:00
1   15  2016-04-01 00:10:20
2   15  2016-04-01 00:13:01
3   15  2016-04-01 00:14:00
4   64  2016-04-01 21:04:59
5   64  2016-04-01 21:13:05
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Isn't `7 64  2016-04-01 21:05:20` within first 15 minutes of `5   64  2016-04-01 21:04:59`? Why is it not included in `new_df`?

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. I considered seconds instead of minutes in reproducing. Will edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the column `timestamp` is of datetime (using [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html))

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
```

Considering that OP wants the timer to start at the beginning of the first `timestamp` for a given `id`, the following will do the work

```
new_df = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x[x.timestamp <= x.timestamp.iloc[0] + pd.Timedelta(minutes=15)])

[Out]:
   id           timestamp
0  15 2016-04-01 00:05:00
1  15 2016-04-01 00:10:20
2  15 2016-04-01 00:13:01
3  15 2016-04-01 00:14:00
4  15 2016-04-01 00:16:00
5  64 2016-04-01 21:04:59
6  64 2016-04-01 21:05:13
7  64 2016-04-01 21:05:20
8  64 2016-04-01 21:05:25
9  64 2016-04-01 21:04:59
```

If OP wants the timer to start at `0 hours`, `0 minutes`, and `0 seconds`, then the following will do the work

```
new_df2 = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x[x.timestamp <= x.timestamp.iloc[0].replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0) + pd.Timedelta(minutes=15)])

[Out]:
      id           timestamp
id                          
15 0  15 2016-04-01 00:05:00
   1  15 2016-04-01 00:10:20
   2  15 2016-04-01 00:13:01
   3  15 2016-04-01 00:14:00
```

**Notes**:

- In both cases, the `new-df` that OP shares in the question is different.
- In the first operation, `x.timestamp.iloc[0]` is selecting the first `timestamp`, and serves the purpose of indicating that the first `timestamp` will be used to define the start date. In the second operation one is doing the same, but instead of keeping that value, one is replacing it with `0 hours`, `0 minutes`, `0 seconds`.
- `.iloc` basically allows one to get rows/columns at integer locations. As we want the first it is `.iloc[0]`.
- One is using [`pandas.Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) to represent the difference between the two dates. In this case it is `15 minutes`.

Comment: @arilwan in the first operation `x.timestamp.iloc[0]` is selecting the first `timestamp`, and serves the purpose of indicating that the first `timestamp` will be used to define the start date. In the second operation one is doing the same, but instead of keeping that value, one is replacing it with `0 hours`, `0 minutes`, `0 seconds`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `new_df` doesn't match the output that you would get according to your description.
But you can use below and verify your desired output:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
d = df.groupby('id').transform(lambda x: (x-x.min()))
d['timestamp'] = d['timestamp'].apply(pd.Timedelta.total_seconds).div(60)
new_df = df[d['timestamp'] <= 15]
```

print(new_df):

```
   id           timestamp
0  15 2016-04-01 00:05:00
1  15 2016-04-01 00:10:20
2  15 2016-04-01 00:13:01
3  15 2016-04-01 00:14:00
4  15 2016-04-01 00:16:00
5  64 2016-04-01 21:04:59
6  64 2016-04-01 21:13:05
```

Comment: Having observed this, I edited the question to match my description.

Comment: You missed one more value for id = 15, and value = 00:16:00 in your desired output in the question.